# Cannot create HALF_FLOAT_OES texture from Uint16Array on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, webgl

I have an iPad Pro 12.9in ML0F2X/A with iOS 12.1.1.  I'm trying to create a half-float WebGL texture, initialized from a Uint16Array:

```
var halfExt = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_half_float");
...
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA,
   halfExt.HALF_FLOAT_OES, new Uint16Array([0, 0, 0, 0]));
```

texImage2D fails with INVALID_OPERATION. I've tested with the latest (January 2019) mobile versions of Safari, Chrome and Firefox on the iPad.  In Safari using remote debugging I can see the log message:

```
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: texImage2D: type HALF_FLOAT_OES but ArrayBufferView is not NULL
```

If I replace the Uint16Array with null, the call succeeds on the iPad but of course my texture is missing.

Here is a snippet:

```js
function log(msg) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

function glEnum(gl, v) {
  for (var key in gl) {
    if (gl[key] === v) {
      return key;
    }
  }
  return "0x" + v.toString(16);
}

// Get A WebGL context
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
if (gl) {

  function getExt(name) {
    var ext = gl.getExtension(name);
    log("Extension " + name + " is " + (ext ? "" : "NOT ") + "supported");
    return ext;
  }

  function checkError(test) {
    var err = gl.getError();
    if (err === 0)
      log(test + ": successful");
    else
      log(test + ": flagged error " + err + " = gl." + glEnum(gl, err));
  }

  var floatExt = getExt("OES_texture_float");
  getExt("OES_texture_float_linear");
  if (floatExt) {

    var tex = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null);
    checkError("Create gl.FLOAT texture with NULL buffer");
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, new Float32Array([0, 0, 0, 0]));
    checkError("Create gl.FLOAT texture with Float32Array buffer");
  }

  var halfExt = getExt("OES_texture_half_float");
  getExt("OES_texture_half_float_linear");
  if (halfExt) {

    var tex = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, halfExt.HALF_FLOAT_OES, null);
    checkError("Create halfExt.HALF_FLOAT_OES texture with NULL buffer");
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, halfExt.HALF_FLOAT_OES, new Uint16Array([0, 0, 0, 0]));
    checkError("Create halfExt.HALF_FLOAT_OES texture with UInt16Array buffer");
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width=100 height=100 style="border:solid black 1px;"></canvas>
```

All tests are successful on my Windows 7 box, in desktop versions of Firefox 60.4ESR and Chrome 71.0.  On iPad, only the last one fails.  How can I make this call succeed on the iPad?

Thanks...

Comment: This has been fixed in the latest builds of Safari. See: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=169999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari does not pass [the WebGL Conformance Test for `OES_texture_half_float`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/extensions/oes-texture-half-float.html)

File a bug [on their bug tracker](https://trac.webkit.org)

Comment: Safari is the new IE 

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I googled for ages for online conformance tests, but my google-fu was inadequate -- those tests are well hidden. Would have saved me a lot of fiddling time....sigh

Comment: Testing current versions of all 3 iPad browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox) in WebGL conformance test, they all fail in exactly the same tests.  Seems to be not just a Safari problem. Non-conformance in the hardware perhaps?

Comment: iPad browsers all use Safari under the hood, they just have different skins because that's all Apple's Terms of Service allow. It's 100% an Apple issue. If Apple allowed other browser engines in iOS instead of only allowing skinned WebKit then all of these issues would be fixed in Chrome and Firefox and likely Apple would have far more pressure to fix Safari.  Note: This is not an iOS issue, Safari on Mac fails the same tests.

Comment: Also what did you google for? Googling for ["webgl conformance tests"](http://google.com/search?q=webgl+conformance+tests) first 3 hits or even ["webgl tests"](http://google.com/search?q=webgl+tests) 2nd hit 

Comment: Ha! Very good point - I can't remember now, it's been so long. I think I searched for browser conformance tests, not specifying WebGL, which was obviously dumb.